# cleaner way to attach event to dynamically rendered field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timeout

I attach a change event to a dynamically rendered form field like this:

```
        var html ='';
        html += '<div class="Gallery-overlayContentWrapper">';
        html += '<center>';
        html += '<h3>'+self.data('uploadHeading')+'</h3>'
        html += parent;
        html += '<form id="Gallery-uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">';
          html += '<input type="hidden" name="Gallery-Parent" id="Gallery-Parent" value="'+self.data('activeFolder')+'" />';
          html += '<p><input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"></p>';
          html += '<p><progress id="Gallery-uploadProgress" value="0" max="100"></progress></p>';
        html += '</form>';
        html += '</center>';
        html += '</div>';

        $(self).find(".Gallery-"+self.data('overlayType')).append(html);
        $(self).find(".Gallery-"+self.data('overlayType')).fadeIn(); //This only covers the thumbs area

        setTimeout(function(){
            $(self).find('#file1').change(function(){
                self.data('uploadFile')(self);
            });
        },1000);
```

This works, but it feels hackish to rely on the element being rendered after 1 sec like this, is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Comment: won't the delegation be more resource demanding, the browser will look for an event whenever anything triggers a change on my page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use timeout, attach it right after appending

```
    $(self).find(".Gallery-"+self.data('overlayType')).append(html);
    $(self).find('#file1').change(function(){
            self.data('uploadFile')(self);
        });
    $(self).find(".Gallery-"+self.data('overlayType')).fadeIn();
```

**or** use delegation

```
$(document).on('change', '#file1', function(){
                self.data('uploadFile')(self);
            });
```

Comment: won't the delegation be more resource demanding, the browser will look for an event whenever anything triggers a change on my page?

Comment: And as for your first suggestion (my initial code minus the timeout thing) there is a risk of that code (setting the change event) executing before the browser is done rendering the html to be appended.

Comment: @MattWelander, you can minimize the performance hit if you use whatever `self` is as the container rather than `document`. Nevertheless, I think the peformance difference between the two is negligible unless you have a **huge** `document`

Comment: @MattWelander, the `change` event cant be fired unless the `input` is visible to the user